# Replace loop using r and grep

Tags: r, function, loops, grepl

I don't know what I'm doing wrong - but I am close - I have made it work once... Can anybody help me out here?

I am trying to replace a column (plik) with a specified word (in this case "A.", if any of the words in  "dlik" are present

```
dlik<-c("Acipenser","cyt b") #list of words to look for
plik<-c("Acipenser oxyrinchus voucher LodgeLab Aoxyrinchus_1 mitochondrion, complete genome",
"Acipenser oxyrinchus voucher LodgeLab Aoxyrinchus_1 mitochondrion, complete genome",
"Acipenser oxyrinchus desotoi mitochondrion, complete genome",
"Acipenser oxyrinchus oxyrinchus mitochondrion, complete genome",
"Acipenser oxyrinchus oxyrinchus isolate ATNNFC-0562 mitochondrion, complete genome",
"Acipenser oxyrinchus oxyrinchus isolate ATNNFC-5C29 mitochondrion, complete genome",
"Acipenser sinensis mitochondrion, complete genome",
"Acipenser sinensis mitochondrion, complete genome",
"Acipenser stellatus complete mitochondiral genome",
"Acipenser stellatus mitochondrion, complete genome",
"Acipenser sturio mitochondrion, complete genome",
"Acipenser sturio mitochondrion, complete genome",
"Polyodon spathula mitochondrial DNA, complete genome"
) #list of words to look in.
```

List of the words to look after (dlik)

```
  for (i in dlik){
   replace(plik,grep(i,plik),"A.")
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done much simpler. No need for the loop:

```
sapply (strsplit(plik," "), 
        FUN=function(x){  
              if (any(x %in% dlik)) return("A") else 
                                    return (paste(x, collapse=" "))})

# [1] "A"                                                   
# [2] "A"                                                   
# [3] "A"                                                   
# [4] "A"                                                   
# [5] "A"                                                   
# [6] "A"                                                   
# [7] "A"                                                   
# [8] "A"                                                   
# [9] "A"                                                   
# [10] "A"                                                   
# [11] "A"                                                   
# [12] "A"                                                   
# [13] "Polyodon spathula mitochondrial DNA, complete genome"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also vectorize by `paste`ing the 'dlik' together, use that in the `grep` to `replace` those elements in 'plik' that matches with the index

```
str1 <- paste0("\\b(", paste(dlik, collapse= "|"), ")\\b")
plik[grep(str1, plik)] <- "A."
plik
# [1] "A."                                                  
# [2] "A."                                                  
# [3] "A."                                                  
# [4] "A."                                                  
# [5] "A."                                                  
# [6] "A."                                                  
# [7] "A."                                                  
# [8] "A."                                                  
# [9] "A."                                                  
#[10] "A."                                                  
#[11] "A."                                                  
#[12] "A."                                                  
#[13] "Polyodon spathula mitochondrial DNA, complete genome"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the `replace` output to `plik`:

```
for (i in dlik){
 plik <- replace(plik,grep(i,plik),"A.")
}
```